# SQL While loop or c# linq foreach?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a credit card payment process stored procedure written in SQL. This is using SQL while to loop through half million payment records. This is horribly slow, because i have to loop through another set of data for each of these payment records and update bunch of tables accordingly. That means while loop inside while loop in sql.

I have to re-write this in c# to improve the performance. We are using LINQ & Entity framework. Can anybody please suggest me if this is going to help or not?

Thanks

Updating my question with modified stored procedure. I have replaced the references to my tables and removed some part of the code. But let me know if this is not clear.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_ProcessPayments]
(
      @UserKey int
)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #TempUserPayments
(
      -- with Columns declared
)


INSERT INTO #TempUserPayments 
SELECT DISTINCT up.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY up.UserKey DESC, up.DateReceived) AS RN  --generate row number
FROM  UserPayment up 
where up.UserKey = @UserKey

CREATE INDEX UP_1 on #TempUserPayments (RN);

        DECLARE @LOOPCOUNTER INT, @ROWCOUNTER INT, @REQUESTEDAMOUNT MONEY, @UPDATEDREQUESTEDAMOUNT MONEY, @AMOUNT MONEY, 
                @AMOUNTNOTAPPLIED MONEY, @APPLIEDAMOUNT MONEY, @SYSTEMKEY INT, @LOOPCOUNTER_PR INT, @ROWCOUNTER_PR INT, @IS_UPDATE BIT


        SELECT @ROWCOUNTER = COUNT(*) from #TempUserPayments;
        SET @LOOPCOUNTER = 1
        WHILE (@LOOPCOUNTER <= @ROWCOUNTER)
        BEGIN
                    SELECT *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mp.Month DESC, mp.PayPriority) AS RN_PR
                    INTO #TempPR
                    FROM Requests pr
                    INNER JOIN Premium mp ON mp.PremiumKey = pr.PremiumKey
                    --Joing couple of other tables here
                    ORDER BY mp.[Month] DESC, mp.PayPriority  

                    CREATE INDEX PR_1 on #TempPR (RN_PR);


                    SELECT @SYSTEMKEY =  SystemKey FROM #TempUserPayments WHERE RN = @LOOPCOUNTER;
                    SELECT @ROWCOUNTER_PR = COUNT(*) from #TempPR;
                    SET @LOOPCOUNTER_PR = 1


                    WHILE (@LOOPCOUNTER_PR <= @ROWCOUNTER_PR)
                    BEGIN
                              SET @IS_UPDATE = 0;                                 

                              IF(@APPLIEDAMOUNT IS NULL OR (@REQUESTEDAMOUNT <> @APPLIEDAMOUNT AND @APPLIEDAMOUNT < @REQUESTEDAMOUNT))
                              BEGIN 

                                    IF(@SYSTEMKEY = 1 OR @SYSTEMKEY = 3)
                                    BEGIN
                                        --Check all the conditions here
                                        SET @IS_UPDATE = 1;
                                    END


                                    IF(@IS_UPDATE = 1)
                                    BEGIN

                                                --Update bunch of requets tables ---

                                                INSERT INTO userpaid
                                                (
                                                  --Column names --
                                                )
                                                VALUES 
                                                (
                                                    --Values --
                                                )
                                    END 
                              END
                    --     END
                          SET @LOOPCOUNTER_PR = @LOOPCOUNTER_PR + 1;

                 END

              SET @LOOPCOUNTER = @LOOPCOUNTER + 1;
              DROP TABLE #TempPR;

        END  

              DROP TABLE #TempUserPayments;
```

END

Comment: Just an opinion: doing the same thing with linq could be worst because it adds network I/O (at least). Instead, I would publish that procedure here and I would ask how to remove RBAR approach (row by agonizing row).

Comment: Doubtful since all you're doing is adding the IO time to get data from the DB and then to update it.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a set based way to work on the data? Will make processing a lot faster if you can think of a way to do it without looping in sql

Comment: I have to apply these payments for multiple requests. You have to keep on updating the amount not applied from these payments and see if there is any amount left and any requests left and so on...

Comment: This seems to be a running total. Which SQL Server version ?

Comment: yes this is kind of running total. SQL server 2012

Comment: I have updated my question with modified sotred procedure. I have replace the references to my tables and removed some part of the code. But let me know if this is not clear

Comment: You need to rewrite this as a CTE with windowed functions and a MERGE statement.

Comment: And better still why are you make your own version of a CURSOR?

Comment: Do you have any sample examples i can take a look? according to my research while loop is better than cursors, so i thought using while loop improve the performance.

Comment: While and Cursors should give [almost] the same performance. Or diff between these two methods should be small.